# Plugins to generate CSS Sprites?

Tags: plugins, css, performance

I see that w3 total cache can't offer CSS sprite generation.  Is there another plugin that can complement this feature?

Thanks.

update: I didn't mean that w3 total cache doesn't allow CSS sprites to be used, but that it doesn't generate them automatically as a way to improve sites performance.  My question is what plugins DO offer that capability.

Comment: Check out CSprite, although it is not up to date so the plugin needs some more work..

Comment: i wan to use this plugin to for my blog [tecnologiageek.com](http://tecnologiageek.com), i thing he asking for a Sprites wordpres plugin.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about how to create css sprites?

Try http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ if the manual way seems too time-consuming.

But yeah, not really a WordPress question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how this can be true. A CSS sprite sheet is just a normal image which is then manipulated with CSS. If you can serve both images and CSS with the W3 Total Cache plugin, you can also serve CSS sprites.

Here's some more information about using CSS sprite sheets: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: I'm using sprites with W3 at http://fraservalleywhitewater.com and http://granadatheater.com

Answer (score 0):

http://spriteme.org/ this site and its script creates sprite from your site. You can use it before you publish your site.

Comment: no longer active, I guess.